# Proving conditional independence using a bayesian belief network / factorization

Tags: bayesian-network, conditional-independence

I have a bayesian belief network with 4 binary variables $A, B, C, D$. I now need to proof that for joint probability distributions factorized according the Bayesian network given below the
conditional independency $A⊥⊥D|C$ always holds.

This by using factorization. Now I know that

$$p(A,B,C,D) = p(A)p(B)p(C|A,B)p(D|C)$$

but how can I go from that to proving that $p(A,D|C) = p(A|C)p(D|C)$ (definition conditional independence)

[image: Bayesian belief network]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:
\begin{align}
P(A,D|C) &= P(A|D,C)P(D|C)\\
&=\frac{P(D,C|A)P(A)}{P(D,C)}P(D|C)\\
&=\frac{P(D|C,A)P(C|A)P(A)}{P(D|C)P(C)}P(D|C)\\
&=\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}P(D|C)\\
&=P(A|C)P(D|C)
\end{align}

Where passages are just Bayes theorem and axioms of probability. I also used that $P(D|C,A) = P(D|C)$ because of redundancy of the conditioning.